# How to attach to COM event in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, events, com

I have followed [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35532/C-COM-Object-for-Use-In-JavaScript-HTML-Including) to create a COM event to be used in javascript. However, I am not a fan of the final attach code?

```
<script for="myComComponent" event="MyFirstEvent(args)" language="javascript">
    function myComComponent::MyFirstEvent(args) {
        alert('event');
    }
</script>
```

What I would like is to be able to do something more like

```
//in the onload
myComComponent.MyFirstEvent = myJavascriptHandler;

//function setup
function myJavascript(args){
    alert('event');
}
```

This works in our older C++ COM event using `IDispatch`, however it does not work with the new C# code. Is there any way to hook the event in the `onLoad`? I just would like to avoid putting the javascript in the HTML...

EDIT:

I tried

```
myComComponent.addEventListener("MyFirstEvent", myJavascriptHandler, true);
```

which should be the same as the dot notation, and this threw an exception that the event was not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are going with this:

```
myComComponent.attachEvent("MyFirstEvent", myJavascriptHandler);
```

This works, removes the code from having to be in the HTML and is fairly clean.